# Hibernate - HQL to fetch a collection from Unidirectional OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have an Class with a unidirectional one to many relationship as follows:

```
public class Order {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="order_item", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="order_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="item_id")})
    public Set<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Normally getting the contents of this order is straightforward:

```
List<Item> items = order.getItems();
```

But for whatever reason I might want to filter my results in some way and retrieve only part of a collection of items such as all items more than a certain price, below a certain stock etc in the fastest way possible (Not returning then all then filtering afterwards).  To do this I would run a HQL query to retrieve the items for a particular order and add some more stuff into my where clause or onto my query object.

Intuitively I would want this behaviour (Which is completely wrong):

```
SELECT jointable.ITEM from order_item as jointable inner join jointable.order where order = :order
```

But of course this is wrong as HQL works in terms of mapped entities, so I cannot use the join table in the query.  So what is the correct way to do this?

**Edit:**

I have found the answer to this question, I want the following Query:

```
Select o.items from Order o where o = ?
```

This allows me to fetch the collection of items for an order, without having to use a bidirectional relationship.  I am now however confused on the second stage of this question, which is how to filter the results of this collection, the most simple example being:

```
Select o.items from Order o where o = ? order by o.items.somenumberfield asc
```

Which returns illegal attempt to dereference collection, so how would I filter my items?

**Edit:**

The ticket solution is actually correct, I misread the solution originally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select item from Order order
inner join order.items item
where order = :order
and ...
```

HQL queries use entities and their associations. The fact that the association uses a join table or not is not important for HQL: you navigate through associations and Hibernate does the appropriate translation to SQL.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to map the other side of this relationship i.e. make this bi-directional mapping.

Then you can use the order number in your HQL:

```
from Item as item where item.amount > :amount and item.order.id = :orderId
```

From the HQL [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-where):

> from Cat as cat where cat.mate.id = 69 
>   The query is efficient and does not require a table join.

The fact that you are trying to do this query suggests that the relationship between a Line and its Order is important!

Comment: No need to make the association bidirectional. See my answer.

Comment: You don't need to. That doesn't mean you shouldn't. The Hibernate docs explain that HQL for this instance is optimised for the situation where you have mapped both sides.

Comment: You have two solutions which will work. The HQL in your edit doesn't make an awful lot of sense. You need to be thinking in terms of Objects and their properties and traversing the object graph.

Comment: I will have to disagree.  I have an order with a collection of items, mapped with a unidirectional one to many relationship.  My items class does not have it's order as a member or this would be a bidirectional relationship.  In other words item.order will not work as item has no order field.