# Hibernate query for retrieving data from one directional one to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, junit, hql

I'm trying to retrieve data using my Hibernate One to Many relation but failing. I'm trying to get all Bookmarked_rooms from Account. Here is my query:

```
public RoomList findBookmarkedRooms(String name) {    
    Query query = em.createQuery("FROM Room r WHERE r.roomid in(SELECT Room_id FROM Bookmarked_rooms a )");
    List rooms = query.getResultList();;
    if (rooms.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return new RoomList(rooms);
    }   
    }
```

Here is my Account and Room entity given separately:

```
    public class Account {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @Column(name="username",unique=true,nullable=false)
        private String username;

        @OneToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "Bookmarked_rooms", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="Account_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="Room_id"))
        private Collection<Room> bookmarkedroom = new ArrayList<Room>();    

//Getters and Setters
    }
```

Room entity:

```
    public class Room {

          @Id
          @GeneratedValue
          private long roomid;

          @Column(name="roomname",unique=true,nullable=false)
          private String roomname;

          private String description;

//Getters and Setters
    }
```

When I run the query I've following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Bookmarked_rooms is not mapped [FROM web.core.models.entities.Room r WHERE r.roomid in(SELECT Room_id FROM Bookmarked_rooms a )]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at web.core.repositories.jpa.JpaAccountRepo.findBookmarkedRooms(JpaAccountRepo.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.findBookmarkedRooms(Unknown Source)
    at web.core.repositories.AccountRepoTest.testFindBookmarkedRooms(AccountRepoTest.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Bookmarked_rooms is not mapped [FROM web.core.models.entities.Room r WHERE r.roomid in(SELECT Room_id FROM Bookmarked_rooms a )]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Bookmarked_rooms is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3678)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.collectionFunctionOrSubselect(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4905)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.inRhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4806)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4473)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    ... 53 more
```

I'm not understanding what is my actual error. If the error is my query, please some one demonstrate me the right query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do it from the other end.

```
select markedroom from Account a
inner join a.bookmarkedroom markedroom
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255072/hibernate-hql-to-fetch-a-collection-from-unidirectional-onetomany-relationship) could help you.

Comment: It's worked. Thanks. :)
But, I'm not fully understanding the code though. Could you please explain me? @Jan

Comment: The first thing is that you don't refer to Column names in the database. You have to use the attribute names directly from java. Second: The Account knows which rooms are booked and you're simply selecting the booked rooms from Account.